# AMD drivers Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm new to Ubuntu. I used Mint in the past ages ago. I decided to jump back to Linux and decided on Ubuntu because of newbie user friendly and support.

Anyway, I'm currently dual booting macOS Big Sur and Ubuntu 20.04. I'm running a 2015 MBPro w/ AMD R9 390X.  My question is do I need to search and install AMD drivers? Or Ubuntu 20.04 has AMD drivers already installed? Thank you!

Comment: Already installed.